# How to efficiently handle Personal Access Token in Azure DevOps organization?

Tags: security, azure-devops, devops

**Context:**

We are using Azure DevOps and we are starting to leverage more and more PATs in our DevOps cycles and processes. We have about 30 users and each one of them creates a bunch of them under their personal account for different use cases.

Here are some scenarios where they are used:

- Self-hosted agents configuration (Windows and dockers)
- API call for Microsoft Teams bots
- Homemade integration with Azure DevOps and other systems
- etc.

Basically, we are starting to loose a bit the control over:

- What kind of PATs are created
- Where are the PATs used
- Which scopes defined on the PATs

As an example, we have some users that create PATs to configure agents. They will give the full access to this PAT, instead of selecting the proper scopes for it. As we know, end users don't really care about security and we are aware that we need educate our developer. However, we still want to have way to control those PATs.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to view in the organization level all the PATs that used?
- Is it possible to remove the possibility for a specific user to create PATs and only give that feature to the admin users?
- Is it possible to revoke all the PATs on the organization level?
- Can you share your experience(s) and tips on how you efficiently handle PATs in your organization and more specifically on the security aspect?

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: It seems that it is only available on the on premise version (VSTS).

Comment: Is there are reason why you wouldn't create a user account specifically to associate to the tokens you need?

Comment: @DevRacker Yes, but this will not prevent other users to generate PATs on their own as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you to restrict the usage of the PATs

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-policies-to-restrict-personal-access-token-scope-and-lifespan/

> Is there a way to view in the organization level all the PATs that used?

Not that I know

> Is it possible to remove the possibility for a specific user to create PATs and only give that feature to the admin users?

From the article, yes it is now possible for the administrator to do so

> Is it possible to revoke all the PATs on the organization level?

Yes it is, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadministration/token%20revocations/revoke%20authorizations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&preserve-view=true

Comment: This is a good news! However, it is still not live yet. I guess that we have to wait a bit before having the full control over our organization PATs since the feature that you linked has just been announced.